# Can't find space in string and specified char , even by simple method

Tags: c, arrays, comparison

I am using this method to find a space or specified word in string.
but this method doesn't works. I've checked the flow many times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char text[50], find;
    int i = 0, sp = 0;
    printf("Enter text: \n");
    scanf("%s", text);
    printf("Enter a char to find:\n");
    scanf("%c", &find);
    while ( text[i] != '\0') // to receive a value untill enter is pressed.
    {
        if (text[i] == find) // count if text[i] is the specified value.
            { sp++; }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", sp); // prints 0 always. how to fix this.
}
```

Comment: So if the character is present then output must be number of times the character appeared?

Comment: yes, this is what i want.@CherubimAnand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` in your code is always assigned with `\n` or the new line character that you enter at the end of scanning your string `text` .Try giving a space in `scanf` statement of `find` :

`scanf(" %c",&find)`

**Why to give a space?**

By giving a space,the compiler omits the `'\n'` character from the previous `scanf`

> **Note**: `scanf("%s",string)` ends scanning when it encounters white space i.e, `'\n'` or `'\0'` or `'\t'` but to account for spaces, try
>   using this `scanf("%[^\n]s",string")`

Comment: thanks it, worked. can you tell me more on that. sorry for that I'm a student. i don't understand why find is always assigned with \n.

Comment: @precious see the note above, scanf stops reading when it encounters a space or newline, so it's carried and stored in next scanf.. That's the reason why find is always assigned with a space

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `scanf()` to read a string of characters with space. As soon as the space is encountered, `scanf()` exits.

Use `fgets()` instead.

---

And as for finding a word in the string, to compare strings use `strcmp()`.

**SIDE NOTE:**

1) Check the return values of `scanf()`

2) Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Comment: Yes, i can use 'fget()' but learning the basis on which this function works and use of this custom function can be useful.

Comment: @Precious, You cannot use `scanf()` for reading strings where there will be spaces. I did not understand your comment properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", fullName);
```

works fine. and receives whole line